# Difference of cov and cor between R and Python

Tags: python, r, numpy

I often use R and I am new to Python.
In R, a demo of computing mean, cov and cor of given matrix 
are given as follows:

```
X = matrix(c(1,0.5,3,7,9,6,2,8,4), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=FALSE)
X
    # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.0    7    2
# [2,]  0.5    9    8
# [3,]  3.0    6    4
M = colMeans(X) # apply(X,2,mean)
M
# [1] 1.500000 7.333333 4.666667
S = cov(X)
S
    # [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,]  1.75 -1.750000 -1.500000
# [2,] -1.75  2.333333  3.666667
# [3,] -1.50  3.666667  9.333333
R = cor(X)
R
        # [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.0000000 -0.8660254 -0.3711537
# [2,] -0.8660254  1.0000000  0.7857143
# [3,] -0.3711537  0.7857143  1.0000000
```

I want to reproduce the above in Python and I try:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,0.5,3,7,9,6,2,8,4]).reshape(3, 3)
X = np.transpose(X) # byrow=FALSE
X
# array([[ 1. ,  7. ,  2. ],
    # [ 0.5,  9. ,  8. ],
    # [ 3. ,  6. ,  4. ]])

M = X.mean(axis=0) # colMeans
M
# array([ 1.5       ,  7.33333333,  4.66666667])
S = np.cov(X)
S
# array([[ 10.33333333,  10.58333333,   4.83333333],
    # [ 10.58333333,  21.58333333,   5.83333333],
    # [  4.83333333,   5.83333333,   2.33333333]])
R = np.corrcoef(X)
R
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.70866828,  0.98432414],
    # [ 0.70866828,  1.        ,  0.82199494],
    # [ 0.98432414,  0.82199494,  1.        ]])
```

Then the results of cov and cor are different. Why?

Comment: The python results match those or R if you get rid of the `transpose` line. The R matrix and numpy arrays are equivalent without the transpose. R working by column, numpy by row.

Comment: Tks a lot! To give consideration to `X.mean(axis=0)`, I choose to keep `X = np.transpose(X)` and then use `np.cov(X, rowvar=False)`@T Burgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `numpy` calculates by row and `R` by column. Either comment out `X = np.transpose(X) # byrow=FALSE`, or use `np.cov(X, rowvar=False)`.

```
np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
array([[ 1.75      , -1.75      , -1.5       ],
       [-1.75      ,  2.33333333,  3.66666667],
       [-1.5       ,  3.66666667,  9.33333333]])
```

The difference is explained in the respective documentation (emphasis mine):

#### Python:

```
help(np.cov)
```

> rowvar : bool, optional
>           If `rowvar` is True (default), then each ***row*** represents a
>           variable, with observations in the columns. Otherwise, the relationship
>           is transposed: each column represents a variable, while the rows
>           contain observations.

#### R:

```
?cov
```

> var, cov and cor compute the variance of x and the covariance or
>   correlation of x and y if these are vectors. If x and y are matrices
>   then the covariances (or correlations) between the ***columns*** of x and
>   the columns of y are computed.

Comment: It is great and very helpful! Tks a lot! @bobbel

Answer (score 2):

If I don't transpose the array in Python, then I have exactly the same answer.

The covariance is computed by row (`X[0]` returns the first row), and I suspect that R stores the data in Fortran order, whereas Python/Numpy uses C order. This explains the difference with the way `mean` is computed, first axis is row in Python, not column.

Comment: It is helpful! Tks! @Matthieu Brucher

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the transpose of the data matrix to numpy.cov() because numpy.cov() considers its input data matrix to have observations in each column, and variables in each row. As you can read from the documentation of np.cov() here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Here in the code provided if you pass the Transposed matrix to np.cov() , you will get the same values as you are getting in R using cov().

Comment: It is helpful! Thank you! @K. Explorer